# iPhone 5 and iOS 8.1 - Not request permission location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In other devices work and the dialogue appears for permission to access location (All devices iOS 7 and iOS 8), but the iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1 not appear that request permission.

Code request permission:

```
var versionString = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil) as NSString
    if versionString.floatValue >= 800 {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {

            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
                    NSLog("Not Accepted")
            } else {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }
        }
    } else {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
            NSLog("Not Accepted")
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

The dialog of request not showing.

A**nd declared on .plist NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription type boolean and YES.**

Comment: Not is duplicate, read question.

Comment: Look at the settings for the app on the iPhone 5? Is the permission already set?

Comment: If the dialog is not showing, are you failing with "Not Accepted" logged?  You may have global location services turned off or that app already set to "Never".

Comment: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription should be a string of what message is shown to the user when requesting permission I believe. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: The app not showing this setting on tab of app.

Comment: Only key description string? nothing key boolean?